# How do I increment a CF session variable on a button onClick?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

How do I increment a Cold Fusion session variable onClick?

```
<input type="submit" value="Next Page" class="button" onClick="incrementMySessionVariable">
```

Currently the button reloads the page on submit (form), but I need to increment my current page session variable onClick.

When the user clicks the button I need to increment the  (CFSET SESSION.currentPage +=1) or decrement (CFSET SESSION.currentPage +=-) the session variable, so I can keep track of what page the user(s) are currently on to calculate if the previous page or next page is disabled as well as the table rows to show.

Comment: a) If you care clicking on a submit button, can't the response page increment the value? b) ColdFusion supports `++` and `--`

Comment: Now I have seen it all... "onClick="<cfset SESSION.currentPage+=1>" does not work".  Wow.

Comment: @SeanCoyne You are taking it out of context. Of course +=1 "works", by it "works" I meant it was simply not exhibiting the behavior I required, probably because of a flaw in the logic.

Comment: No, it doesn't work because you can't execute server side code in an "onclick" handler of a button.  That is what I was surprised about. It has nothing to do with any logic, it has everything to do with a lack of understanding of server side vs client side code.

Comment: [The ColdFusion request/response process](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html)

Comment: @Leigh thank you for providing the link that explains Cold Fusion client/severside. Much more helpful thank snarky comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the button a name, such as `nextpage` then a `nextpage` var will appear when the button click reloads the page.

```
<input type="submit" value="Next Page" class="button" name="nextpage">
```

So, now that you've named the button, add this to near the top of your cfm page (or at least before you start reading SESSION.currentpage)

```
<cfif isDefined("nextpage")><cfset SESSION.currentPage += 1></cfif>
```

This will work for a previous page button as well.  That button should have `name="prevpage"` and then add a similar line like this:

```
<cfif isDefined("prevpage")><cfset SESSION.currentPage -= 1></cfif>
```

Comment: It finally exhibited the behavior I required. I have to follow your instructions but I have to do a -2 on for previous. <cfif isDefined("prevpage")><cfset SESSION.currentPage = SESSION.currentPage-2></cfif>

Comment: That's good it's working for you.  If you're having to do a -2 for previous, then there must be a +1 happening on accident somewhere, maybe in the onClick attribute from your initial version?  There should only be one spot where the page is incremented, which is in the isDefined("nextpage")

Comment: Yeah, found it and fixed it.